# Python ctypes DLL method call works interactively, only one call as script

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I need to use a DLL (of which I don't have the source) to communicate with some other process. I'm using ctypes, like so:

```
gcs = CDLL('some_dll.dll')
gcs.comm_init(byref(socket_id), 0, 'localhost')
data_out = (c_double*3)(); data_in = (c_double*3)();
while True:
  rv = gcs.comm_exchange(byref(socket_id), data_in, data_out)
  if rv == communication_return_code['SUCCESS']:
    print('received data_out :\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n' % tuple(data_out))
  else:
    errmsg = some_function(rv)
    print('Error: %s\n' % errmsg)
    break
```

When running this in an interactive Python prompt, comm_exchange updates the data_out array each time as expected (it'd work as many times as I'd try). However, when running as a script, it updates the data_out array only once, then a connection error occurs at the second call to exchange. The problem is I can't track down what's causing the connection error in the library, as I don't have the source of the library.

What I've tried:
- filling data_in and data_out with zeros, however that seemed unnecessary (printing them whilst running as a script showed zeros also when I did not explicitly do that)
- passing socket_id and data structures in different ways, without `byref`, using `pointer` and `addressof`. Any working code gave the same result, no improvement.
- garbage collection: tried switching it off using `gc.disable()`, using `global` for gcs. No effect noticed

Any ideas on how to tackle this issue?

Python 2.5.4, ctypes 1.0.3 (can't upgrade Python because of other dependencies).

Comment: Even without the source, the DLL is probably mostly just making WinSock calls, which can you see by debugging it as native code (or by using one of the strace/dtrace/truss ports to Windows). And if it has debug symbols, even if you can't see the source, you might get something by looking at the function names in the stack.

Comment: Another thing you can try is Wiresharking the network traffic to see if anything's different in the two cases.

Comment: Finally, you can try to do some of the same things the interactive interpreter does to see if they make any difference. If you're not running the script with a console, do that first, because that's easy. Then you can try starting up a prompt with `cmd` and calling this code as the response to any input. You can also try running the interactive interpreter in IDLE, and in IPython, to see if that makes it work more like the script.